# Dismiss Bootstrap Badges Notification

Tags: php, jquery

[Navbar Image](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/9462/OEW8ov.png)

The badge show number like chat notification, i want to ask how to dismiss notification badge if i click that announcement

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?? share the code..

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't share any code — so it's hard to answer the question — but a pretty generic way of hiding something with jQuery would look something like this:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".badge").hide();
});
```

I'm assuming your HTML looks something like this

```
<p><a href="#" id="hide">Announcement</a><span class="badge">1</span></p>
```